# Modifying the source cell

Tags: excel

Excel

I will make it simple to understand what I need.

I have an excel with 2 sheets.
1- the database: containing a table with name + id + mobile number

2- the search sheet.

On the search sheet i type the ID then its returned a result with the name and mobile number. (I can use even vlookup or index)

Anyway, what I want is: when the results extracted from the Database sheet to the Search sheet. I want to modify it and directly get reflected to the source cell from the database sheet.

I tried to use vlookup but it’s impossible to do what i want to do

Comment: Only way to use `VBA` coding. Formula can't modify any value. They can only return calculated results.

Comment: A detail that will change my answer: Are you actually using a table, such that something like `=DbTable[MyFirstColumnName]` works?

Comment: @JSmart523 i don’t get you. I just want to extract data from sheet1 to sheet2. The I want to modify the data in sheet2. Then it’s got reflected in sheet1.